# Connecting MySQL with Python

Tags: python, mysql

I was trying to connect mysql with python. I used the command "sudo pip install mysql-python" and the message I got,

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Downloading MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 110kB 1.4MB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-EdaCnd/mysql-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-EdaCnd/mysql-python
```

how can I solve the problem?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` install this first.

Answer (score 1):

You need mysql_config installed. On Debian/Ubuntu you would use this command to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Assuming you have administrator privileges on your machine. It could also be that mysql_config is not in your path, you should look into that as well.

Comment: Thanks. After doing that I got the message "sudo: apt-get: command not found"

Comment: What operating system are you using?